# Arcpy connect to folder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arccatalog, list

Would anyone know if there is a way to automate (in arcpy) Arcgis's [Connect to Folder](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00660000044p000000) function from a list of directories? What I am after is an automated process to take a list of directory file paths, map them to my folder connections in ArcCatalog and rename the folders.

Example of a list of directories

```
mylist = ["D:\Animal_Locations\Apes","D:\Animal_Locations\Alligator","D:\Animal_Locations\Ants"]
```

Image below shows the example of the connected folders with the original names changes. The renaming will also be automated and based on the file path from the list.

[image]

Comment: Check this out: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82320/can-a-folder-connection-in-arcmap-catalog-window-be-added-using-python

Comment: They're all on D:\, so just connect to D:\ then use each folder... it is not good to have too many connections in ArcCatalog as each one is polled on startup; too many connections = very slow startup. In reality you don't need to connect to a folder to use the data in a script, it's only for browsing in ArcCatalog (like a shortcut).

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson. Thanks for the headsup. I wasn't aware about having to many connections slow things down - but when I think about it, it does make scene.

Comment: @Aaron. Thanks for the link. Looks like its not achievable and based on what MichaelMiles-Stimson, may not be a good practice to bulk automate connections.