# Recover Folder Connections

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have upgraded from ArcGIS 10.0 to ArcGIS 10.3.1 and I noticed that I lost my Folder Connections in the process.  Is there a way to recover my folder connections from ArcGIS 10.0?  I have all my local files on the c: drive backed up.

Comment: See [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82320/can-a-folder-connection-in-arcmap-catalog-window-be-added-using-python) question. It should work if you bring over the old files.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up copying my whole ArcCatalog folder to the 10.3.1 location and that restored my folder connections.
However, I also performed a test and discovered that when I added a new folder connection, in ArcMap, that the file C:...\ESRI\Desktop10.0\ArcCatalog\ArcCatalog.gx file was updated with the same date and time as when the folder connection was created.  I suspect that's the file that contains the folder connection information.  If anybody can confirm that, please post a comment here.

Answer (score -1):

esri documentation on recovering connections

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011442